# How can i display only the content of a website?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I need to display only a part of the website, basically the CONTENT part of the website.

I can display the website with uiwebkit but, i dont want to display the entire website but only the CONTENT part of the webpage. I have no idea how to do this , as i have never done this and i did some google search but could not find anything on ios / swift.

[image]

How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **WKNavigationDelegate** which allow you to implement **did finish** the function of **webview** in this function you can hide specific content of website.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {


    let removeelementid = "javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByClassName('td-header-menu-wrap-full td-container-wrap')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " + "})()"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeelementid) { (res, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            //do any thing
        }
    }
}



func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

as you can see i am removing specific content of web by its class name **td-header-menu-wrap-full td-container-wrap**

Go to that web site right click -> click inspect. pick class names of content and call in this function . hope this will help you.

Comment: check weather footer is your class name or id name .. if it is id then replace getElementsByClassName with getElementsById

Comment: It was my mistake . Figured it out . Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to do this stuff BEFORE the webpage is displayed on the screen? Right now it displays the page and removes the items from the page in like 0.5sec. User can still see the original page for 0.5secs

Comment: well i didn't try this but you can check out this function . it might help you to remove content webpage is displayed. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455621-webview

Comment: you can also check all navigation delegates functions here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate